# How to auto route traffic between networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

I have 1 windows 10 computer connected to two networks (3g and wifi).
The 3g connection (IPVPN via netstick) is used to connect to a company's network and the wifi connection used for internet.
I want to use both network simultaneously. however, when both connection are online, the computer uses the 3g connection and I can't reach the internet. I tried to change the metric, than the internet worked but I have no access to the company network.

How can I set that the computer will try to connect to a site/IP thru one network (3g or wifi) and if the site is not reachable in that network, the computer will try the other network?

Comment: Please provide more information. Which Operating System is used by the computer ? Does the company network connection require a VPN ? Both are very important details in order to be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Network and sharing center
3. Change adapter settings
4. Right click on you wifi network adapter
5. Properties
6. TCP IP4/TP6
7. Properties
8. Advance
9. uncheck automatic metric and type "5"
10. Do the same thing to 3G and give it number "10"

Basically your computer will pick up the adapter with the lower number first and use it to connect to internet and the second for sharing files..

**Change the priority of your connections:**

- Open your Adapter Settings (Control Panel\Network and
  Internet\Network Connections)
- Click Alt to pull up the menu bar
- Select Advanced then Advanced Settings
- Change the order of the connections so that the connection you want
  to have priority is top on the list.

[image]

Comment: This works in the simple case when you only need to reach your immediate subnet, but most corporate networks are a bit larger – so trying to reach the parts of LAN outside the current subnet will end up hitting the highest-priority 'default' route anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which OS is used on the router (I'm going to guess Windows), but the generic answer is to add a *more specific* route for your company network.

- Basic routing tables are longest-prefix-match, in terms of bits (the number after the `/`), so a specific network route always wins over the default route. The metric is only important when comparing routes of identical prefixes.
- By default, hosts have a default route, e.g. `0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1` or `::/0 via 2001:db8::1`; plus a route for its own subnet, e.g. `192.168.1.0/24 direct` or `2001:db8::/64 direct`.

  Since you have two connections, both of which have a gateway configured, that means you also have two "default" routes, and the metric decides which one to use.
- However, if you had a route for a specific network, it would *always* win over the default routes, due to having a longer prefix.

So if your workplace only had a single subnet, you wouldn't have to do anything – the automatically added subnet route would take care of it.

But to achieve the desired result with a network *larger* than just your subnet,

1. Set the Internet connection to higher priority – i.e. make its metric smaller than the work connection's.
2. Write down the "default gateway" used by your work connection.
3. Add a route for your work LAN through the work connection, using that same gateway. In Windows, you'll need to do this through the command line, e.g.:

   ```
   route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 <gateway_ip_goes_here>
   route add 172.16.0.0 mask 255.240.0.0 <gateway_ip_goes_here>
   route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 <gateway_ip_goes_here>
   ```

   (Since I don't know *what* network your workplace actually uses, the above example sets broad routes that cover all "private LAN" addresses.)

   If it works, repeat the same command using `route add -p` so that Windows will remember it across reboots. If it *doesn't* work, use `route delete 10.0.0.0` or whatever.